# Cross-platform Mercurial settings

Tags: dropbox, mercurial, cross-platform

I have project files in Dropbox, VC-ed with Mercurial. This way I can work on the same code in Windows at work and in Linux at home. The central repository is on our institute Samba file server, which I have mounted in Linux (as /mnt/server/) and in Windows (as a network drive Z:). Now, Mercurial stores the location of the central repo (for push/pull) in .hg/hgrc. And the path there is, of course, either the Linux or the Windows one. As a result, I should always edit the file or pull/push only in one OS.

Is there a better practice/way to go? I wouldn't like having two branches for two operating systems since I already have a few branches according to what I am working on.

Comment: Why do you need Dropbox *and* Mercurial?

Comment: @sblair - i think he's using dropbox as a repo sync. service between home/work.

Comment: @sblair: Exactly. Plus to sync between OSes. At work, I have both Windows and Linux. I want to be able to work on the same files in both OSes. Dropbox does that. I don't want two different branches for two different OSes because branches should be created according to tasks, not according to where I access those tasks.

Comment: you **can** have one VCS (mercurial) and one codebase on any amount of OSes and workplaces -just use external repo (private Bitbucket, f.e) and perform pull-push cycle with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one project with one path to the repository then you can move the [paths] section out of .hg/hgrc and put it instead in the per-user config file on each computer, $HOME/.hgrc on Unix and %HOME%\.hgrc on Windows.

Another option is to put both Unix and Windows aliases into the [paths] section:

```
[paths]
win = z:\path\to\repo
unix = /mnt/server/path/to/repo
```

And then specify the alias when pushing/pulling:

```
hg push win
hg push unix

hg pull win
hg pull unix
```

Comment: The first option doesn't work for me: I have more than one project under version control. However the second one looks just like what I need. However to make it work I need to specify this alias in TortoiseHg. Do you think it's possible? I couldn't find the way.

Comment: Aliases can be managed nicely from the Synchronize view (there's a button on the toolbar or just choose menu View-->Synchronize). (I'm using TortoiseHg 2.1.3). You use the same view to sync to/from a selected alias.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better practice/way to go?

Yes.

**Idea 1**
Use ssh:// or http:// protocol instead of file://, where FQDNs of remote repo are the same

**Idea 2**
Just pull/push ftom/to work/home repo (and don't use Dropbox for repo syncs)

Comment: SSH and HTTP seems to be a good solution. I should check with our admin if our server provides this option.